# Wordpress to customly read JWPlayer Plugin's "Playlist" items by using its "playlistid"?

Tags: wordpress, function, customization, jwplayer, playlist

In Wordpress (3.8.1) and JW Plugin (v2.1.2) with JW Player (v5), I need to read off the items contained in the Playlists of the [JWPlayer Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/jw-player-plugin-for-wordpress/).

### Normally

The **JWPlayer Plugin** works like this, via Shortcode:

```
[jwplayer playlistid="1234"]
```

.. then a `Video Player` will be being rendered on the Page, together with a Playlist inside.

---

### What i want to do (The Customizing)

So now how do i customly do by myself .. **if i want to know (or pull out) the items inside a Playlist**, by using its `playlistid` or `1234`.

Lets say in a totally New Page (**without using JWPlayer Shortcodes**), i will use my **own Custom Shortcode**, like:

```
[playlistitems id="1234"]
```

(The `id` is the ID of JWPlayer "existing" Playlist)
Then **The New Page** will be showing (just list down) the Items inside, like:

```
- intro.mp4
- chapter-1.mp4
- chapter-6.mp4
- wrapup.mp4
```

.. something like that **which needs to be done by my custom module (or) functions**.

---

In more simple words:

- I want to list down the Items inside the JWPlayer's `playlist` (by using its ID)
- How does JWPlayer reads a Playlist. Then i may need to clone its function.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using JW5 or JW6?

Comment: Hi @EthanJWPlayer it is JW5

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer but i think the JW player version is not the point, but the plugin version is. Am i right, pls?

Comment: Yes, but we really do not support changing the source of the plugin though.

Comment: Yes thanks much anyway. I'll be finding it out myself :)

Comment: Okay, np, let me know if you find anything :)

Comment: Hi @EthanJWPlayer i've got it done with my customizations. Please kindly look in the previous Email Thread, we are on. I have a quick question to ask about the Caption Font "SIZE" in the Playlists. Thanks! :)

Comment: Glad you got it, I will check the email!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, after making a Custom Shortcode *(this can be found on standard WP docs)*, then by direct calling one of JW player's function, from the Template File, like:

```
generate_playlist( '1234' );
```

It will then return a complete Array of the JW Playlist Object, so we can parse it out.